# How to set the default value for input type number

Tags: html, reactjs

I have one input field having type number. I want to set its default value to 1. I have tried using defaultValue attribute in various ways but nothing worked for me. Is there any solution to set the default value using html or ReactJS.

Comment: document.getElementById("numberId").defaultValue = "1";

Comment: <input className="col-sm-2" id="numberId" type="number" min="1" max="10" defaultValue="1" disabled={this.state.goodChecked}/>

Comment: <input className="col-sm-2" id="numberId" type="number" min="1" max="10" defaultValue={1} disabled={this.state.goodChecked}/>

Comment: I have tried these many solutions, but nothing is working for me. Please guide me how we can set default value of input type to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `.defaultValue`

```js
document.getElementById("1").defaultValue = "1";
```

```html
<input type="text" id="1">
```

Comment: Is there a way that defaultValue of a disabled input field should not post

Comment: If you don't want a disabled input field to post, don't give it a name field.